# Loading dialog while BrowserComponent is loading

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to display something like a dialog while BrowserComponent is loading instead of the white page?

Answer (score 0):

Not a `Dialog` but you can show an `InteractionDialog` and it should work.

A `Dialog` is a separate `Form` with a background effect so you'd effectively move to another form an stop the loading. An `InteractionDialog` is a Container placed in the layered pane on top of the app and works similarly to a `Dialog`.

You can use the `OnLoad` event to dismiss the dialog.